# my both Varible showing same sotred array but one is asscending another is decending ,why showing same?

Tags: javascript

```
// const array1 = [1, 30, 4, 21, 100000, 99];
// const asscending=array1.sort((a,b)=>a-b); //for asending
// console.log(asscending);
// array1.sort((a,b)=>b-a); //for desecnding
// console.log(array1);
// console.log(asscending);
```

```
// output[ 1, 4, 21, 30, 99, 100000 ][ 100000, 99, 30, 21, 4, 1 ][ 100000, 99, 30, 21, 4, 1 ]
```

My doubt is why asscending variable is changed and how to resolve it

assecending variable will not channge

Comment: Make a copy first: `const asscending=[...array1].sort((a,b)=>a-b);`

Answer (score 0):

.sort will return a reference to the original object, instead of copying it to a new one. So both variables point at the same array in memory.

You can find proof of this with:

console.log(array1 === ascending);

In order to avoid that you can create a copy of the array before sorting it:

Const ascending = array1.slice().sort()
or
const ascending = […array1].sort